# Is there any way to retrieve sharepoint documents which are rated by current user?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have tried rest search endpoint to retrieve documents properties but there is no any information about who rated it. Any help using rest or rest-search will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: maybe something like https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228560/use-rest-api-to-like-or-rate-a-sharepoint-list-item

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen they are using a single list to fetch item details. That may work if we can get RatedBy column value somewhere in search response. Because in my case there are lot of libraries from where I need to fetch data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CSOM to retrieve this

```
function getItemRating(listTitle,itemId, success,error)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

    context.load(item);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var ratingEntry = {};
            ratingEntry.AverageRating = item.get_item('AverageRating');
            ratingEntry.RatingCount = item.get_item('RatingCount');
            ratingEntry.Ratings = item.get_item('Ratings');
            success(ratingEntry);           
        },
        function(sender,args)
        {
            error(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}

//Usage
getItemRating('Documents',5,function(ratingEntry){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ratingEntry)); 
},
function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: This is possible but we cannot implement this in SPFx webpart right?